# Google Calendar API FreeBusy External Users

Tags: node.js, permissions, google-calendar-api

Is it possible to use oauth2 to access the Google calendar of several Google account users external from any user running my app?  Can I run the free-busy API call to find out when the external users are available?  If possible, do all external users in this call have to be in the same organization?  To identify the users, do I need their email addresses?  Can I write this in Node.js to run on a server?  How can I grant access to the Node.js application running the free-busy query for all the external users being queried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Google Identity services](https://developers.google.com/identity?csw=1) to call the API and get the necessary token to access the Google Calendar for web applications, either user ["Sign-in with Google"](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview) or ["One tab."](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap)

Both options can be used on Mobile devices and web applications.

You can find more information about the authentication with calendar data API in [this documentation](https://support.google.com/code/answer/64253) or more information about the OAuth client library for Node.js [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis#oauth2-client).